# Is there any other method to stream camera without using .sdp file in wowza?

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

I'm new in Wowza. I need to know whether there is any method to stream camera  without creating .sdp file.

Comment: What kind of camera are you using? Is it an RTSP-based camera, where you can playback an output RTSP stream?

Comment: We are using H264 camera for streaming in wowza. It is a RTSP based camera, we are playing the output stream in web and mobile devices(android and iOS).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an RTSP-based camera, and presumably playing back the output stream with the following URI

```
rtsp://[cameraIP]:[port]/[app]/[stream]
```

Then you can re-stream this using MediaCaster in Wowza.

1. From the Manager UI, create a stream file and have this point to the URI from your camera.
2. Go to Applications, and select your live application.
3. Click on Stream Files, and you should see the stream file that you created. Click on the connect icon next to it.

You should now see the stream file as an Incoming Stream for your application. Check that you are able to playback the output stream from Wowza by clicking on the Incoming Stream, and selecting Test Players.

The URI for your IP camera would differ depending on what vendor/model you are using. Here are some common formats from some IP cameras.

```
Axis rtsp://[camera-ip-address]:554/axis-media/media.amp
Panasonic rtsp://ip_adx/MediaInput/h264
SONY rtsp://[login:password@][camera domain name or IP address]/media/video1
```

Make sure that you can playback the IP camera URI using a third party tool (VLC is great for this) that is installed on your Wowza server, so you can make sure that it is reaching your server correctly.

Comment: Thanks Michelle for your help, let me try with this. As I need to ask one more thing, can we write our module in wowza to recoding the video files and store it to another location, if we use the stream files.(I am new to wowza that's why I am asking).

Comment: You can implement the IMediaStreamActionNotify3 or the newer (recommended) IStreamRecorderActionNotify interfaces to start and stop recordings, and the IMediaWriterActionNotify interface to move the recordings once it is completed. There are example source codes on the Wowza website, and should also be documented in the Javadocs that comes with your Wowza installation under documentation.

Comment: Thanks Michelle, Let me try with that. One more  thing to ask, its about how to use the srtp in wowza. I want to stream a camera to wowza using the srtp method, so please help me with this to.

Comment: The easiest way is to add the crypto keys through the SDP data. But since you are looking for alternatives to SDP, you can [inject the key info via the API](https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?45544-SRTP-(secure-RTP)-support-in-Wowza-Streaming-Engine&p=157872#post157872).

Comment: Thanks Michelle, We already find the link in which the crypto key is added to the sdp file , I want to know how we can implement this(Encryption using ffmpeg) in the wowza for streaming. how to decrypt the incoming stream and how to play the stream ?,I have no idea about how to decrypt the stream before passing the url to mobile device or player.

Comment: As long as you include the crypto key in the SDP file or through the Wowza API, your Wowza software would decrypt the incoming stream. For playback, you will need to implement the example API from the page so that the keys are provided.

Comment: Thanks, ok we include the crypto key in the SDP file, is it necessary to provide the crypto key along with the camera start stream command? like Streaming ip=[ server IP ] port=[ port no ] type=start text= timeout=60 quality=sub [ crypto key ].

Comment: Since the crypto key is in the SDP file, when you connect the SDP file to your Wowza server (via the Manager, Applications > {appName} > Stream Files), your Wowza server should then read the crypto key and connect to the encoder. Here's the link on connecting an SDP file: https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?38-How-to-set-up-live-streaming-using-a-native-RTP-encoder-with-SDP-file